# "Означающий" или "обозначающий"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Это слово означает..." или "Это слово обозначает..."? Равноправны ли эти два слова? Или, в данном случае, "обозначает" — это разговорное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если кратко, то значимой разницы в использовании, значении, нормативности не вижу.
Если и есть некоторые стилистические отличия, то не принципиальные.

Если подробнее, то так.

На уровне философии или в математизированных текстах и программировании особенно "обозначать" и "обозначать" используются (или могут быть использованы) с разным смыслом. 
Если очень примитивно, **обозначать** - по определению, постулату, субъективной посылкой: "обозначим число овец в отаре через X". 
Если **означать**, то идет речь о некоем силлогизме, на основании которого устанавливается означаемым и означачащим: "название *эллиптический интеграл* означает, что подынтегральное выражение принадлежит рассмотренному выше множеству эллиптических функций".

Вместе с тем, даже в математике это различие относится скорее к вспомогательному описательному языку и его не следует абсолютизировать.

В конкретном же предложении "слово обозначает..." и "слово означает..." означают (и обозначают) одно и тоже с точностью, может, до малосущественных стилистических различий.
Примеры (Марк Из) не выглядят не только бесспорными, но и сколько-нибудь убедительными. Во-первых, само понятие абстрактный / конкретный на такой уровне нуждается в доопределении, а во-вторых, и в главных, тут, как и в математике, можно говорить разве что о разнице между уже известным (означать) и вновь водимым понятием (обозначать), сопоставляемым с данным словом.

Потому "слово мораль" **и обозначает,  и означает** приводимое понятие, а слово ложка - и подавно. Для русского оно столовый прибор означает, для иностранца, впервые слово услышавшего, - обозначает. Впрочем, как сказал, все весьма условно. Если кто-то скажет что все с "точность до наоборот", по сути возразить ему будет нечего. Придется согласиться и на "наоборот".

Comment: Доопределяю.

*Слово "behemothus" **означает** "бегемот". Слово "behemothus" **обозначает** бегемота.*

Это моё мнение, но если слова "означает" и "обозначает" поменять местами фразы будут звучать как-то не по-русски. В первом случае, латинское слово мы переводим русским (абстрактное понятие объясняем с помощью другого абстрактного понятия) Во втором - абстрактное понятие объясняем конкретным (можем увидеть, услышать, пощупать) животным.

Т.е. "означает" - имеет знак (слово), "обозначает" - наделяет знаком (словом). Вполне себе первые словарные значения.

Comment: Слово "behemothus" и означает, и обозначает только Вашего покорного.
Оно выдумано как коннотация слов "бегемот"  и "свинтус".

Для зануд. В сети иногда проскакивает оное "слово", и даже тезки, но это никак не сказывается на означенном положении. Копиратов на ник не заявляю и мне их никто не предъявлял.

Answer (score 6):

Означать - это значить, иметь значение.

Обозначать - слово многозначное. 1-  отмечать, выделять знаком. 2 - иметь значение.

Т.е. в одном из значений эти слова -  синонимы.

Comment: В примерах "это слово обозначает..." первое из указанных значений просто невозможно. Т.е. я бы без всяких оговорок сказал, что представленные варианты синонимичны.

Answer (score 4):

*Слово означает* - это вступление к абстрактному определению.
Слово "мораль" **означает** сложившиеся в обществе нормы поведения.

*Слово обозначает* - вступление к конкретному описанию.
Слово "ложка" **обозначает** столовый прибор, представляющий собой небольшую лопатку с углублением в широкой части.

То есть, "означаем" мы какое-либо слово смыслом, а "обозначаем" имеющийся смысл (предмет, явление) словом.